# Send data through get method to a TemplateView in Django

Tags: python, ajax, django

I am using `openpyxl` to download querysets into .xlsx files, and for that I need to use a TemplateView. I am calling the TemplateView by using JQuery-Ajax, I send a single variable that I need to use as a parameter in my queryset, but I don't know how to use the value of that variable in the TemplateView.

By default `openpyxl` overrides `GET` method, using this:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
```

And I have tried to get the variable by this code:

```
    context = self.get_context_data()
    valor=context["number"]
```

With that code I'm getting this error:

```
500: KeyError at /the_url/
'numbers'
```

In the error show this:

```
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/the_url/?number=34


Request information:
GET:
number = '34'

POST: No POST data

FILES: No FILES data
```

Where number is the name of the `GET` variable that I'm sending trough Ajax.

So, how can I get the `GET` variable value in a TemplateView?

Comment: have you tried to directly access `self.request.GET` in your `def get_context_data()`?

Comment: @AndreyZarubin so, my code will be like this? `valor=self.request.GET["number"]`

Comment: pretty much yes. I would suggest to use self.request.GET.get('number') instead of self.request.GET.['number'] to avoid KeyError

Comment: @AndreyZarubin ok, I'm going to try, and sorry for "double" answer, I also answered on your Answer

Comment: @AndreyZarubin I think is working, I don't get a 500 error now, but my file isn't downloading, probably there's something wrong in my code, but I think that the main issue of my question has been answered.

Comment: @AndreyZarubin Thank you :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to access your variable via `self.request.GET.get('number')` in the `get_context_data` method.

Example of template view (Python3 version)

```
class MyTemplateView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'path/to/tempplate.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        valor = self.request.GET.get('number')
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Comment: I don't get it, so, how must it be? What do you min "in the mehtod"? where should I put the code?  `context = self.get_context_data()` and later `valor=context.self.request.GET.get('number')`  ??

Comment: It depends on where you need your variable. In fact, `self.request.GET.get('number')` regardless of the method. You should be able to use `valor=self.request.GET.get('number')`whenever you need `valor`.